# I want to access an image file (with 5 sec interval) placed at a server in a local network

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, lan

I want to access an image file (with 5 sec interval) placed at a server in a local network so i can get the update of that server's availability. I am scripting in javascript. But the problem is that once onload() is completed, the browser stores the file in cache. If I remove the cache manually, the script runs perfectly.
Is there any other solution using IE, CHROME and EDGE?

Comment: Please show us what you have tried already.

Answer (score 0):

In order to bypass cache add the argument `true` inside the `location.reload()` function.

```
location.reload(true);
```